# Maven Dependency Resolution Issue for GeoServer GS:WPS

Tags: java, shared-libraries, postgis, geoserver, wps

I am encountering an issue while building a GeoServer wps using Maven, and I could use some guidance.

Error Description:

I am attempting to build a GeoServer wps using Maven (mvn clean install). However, I'm facing a dependency resolution problem related to the gs-wps library. The error suggests that Maven cannot find the artifact in the specified repository (https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/geoserver-releases/). I Already tried all versions but same error. i checked the Repository and i didnt found the gs:wps. Error: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.geoserver:Test:jar:2.8-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.geoserver:gs-wps:jar:2.23.0 (absent): org.geoserver:gs-wps:jar:2.23.0 was not found in https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/geoserver-releases/ during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of osgeo-snapshot has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights into resolving Maven dependency issues for GeoServer extensions, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Is there an alternative repository, a recommended version, or any other solution to successfully resolve this dependency?

Thank you in advance for your help!

pom.xml

```
 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <gt.version>29.0</gt.version> <!-- GeoTools version -->
    <gs.version>2.23.0</gs.version> <!-- GeoServer version -->
    <jts.version>1.18.2</jts.version> <!-- JTS version -->
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- GeoTools dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-process</artifactId>
        <version>${gt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geoserver.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>gs-wps-core</artifactId>
        <version>${gs.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JTS (Java Topology Suite) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.locationtech.jts</groupId>
        <artifactId>jts-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jts.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.geoserver</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-wps</artifactId>
<version>2.23.0</version> <!-- Use the appropriate version -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version> <!-- Replace with the appropriate version -->
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Other plugins... -->
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo-snapshot</id>
        <name>OSGeo Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/geoserver-releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
</repositories>
```